# Show $z^\frac{m}{n} = \exp[\frac{m}{n}\log{z}]$ for integers $m$ and $n$

Tags: complex-analysis

ORIGINAL: I decided to work with the right side and did the following:

\begin{align}z^\frac{m}{n}&=\exp\Bigl[\frac{m}{n}\log(z)\Bigr]\\\\
&=\exp\bigl[\log(z^\frac{m}{n})\bigr]\\\\
& = z^\frac{m}{n}\end{align}

I'm still learning complex variables so there is a big chance I missed something important but my question is: is this valid?

UPDATED: Thanks to Sangchul Lee, I learned $z^\frac{m}{n}$ is commonly defined by $\exp\Bigl[\frac{m}{n}\log(z)\Bigr]$ so my original answer is not meaningful. In addition, thanks to zimbra314's hint, I was able to produce a better answer.

\begin{align}
z^\frac{m}{n}&=\exp\Bigl[\frac{m}{n}\log(z)\Bigr]\\\\
&=\exp\Bigl[\frac{m}{n}\bigl(\ln(|z|)+i(\theta+2\pi k)\bigr)\Bigr]\\\\
&= e^{\bigl [\frac{m}{n}\ln(|z|)\bigr]}\exp\Bigl [i\frac{m}{n}(\theta+2\pi k)\Bigr]\\\\
&= e^{\bigl [\ln(|z|^\frac{m}{n})\bigr]} \Bigl[\cos\bigl(\frac{m}{n}(\theta+2\pi k)\bigr)+i\sin\bigl(\frac{m}{n}(\theta+2\pi k)\bigr)\Bigr]\\\\
& = |z|^\frac{m}{n}\bigl[\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigr]^\frac{m}{n}\\\\
&= \Bigl[|z|\bigl(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)\bigl)\Bigr]^\frac{m}{n}\\\\
&=z^\frac{m}{n}
\end{align}

Comment: *How* do you define $z^{\frac mn}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I would define it as $(x+iy)^\frac{m}{n}$

Comment: And how do you define $(x+yi)^{\frac mn}$?

Comment: I could use De Moivre's Formula to express $z^\frac{m}{n}$ as $r^\frac{m}{n}(\cos(\frac{m}{n}\theta + i\sin\frac{m}{n}\theta)$. I'll give that a shot and see how it works, thanks!

Comment: I tried it but hit a dead end, I wrote the $\cos$ and $\sin$ in terms of exponentials and simplified the expression but I couldn't seem to go any further. Any more tips? Thank you again for your help, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I really would like to help, but there is *nothing* I can do until you tell me what does $z^{\frac mn}$ mean to you. Not to mention $\log z$, of course.

Comment: As pointed out in other comments, you cannot show something equals something until you know what they are. And in this particular context, we really need to know how $z^{m/n}$ is defined because, in most literature, $z^{m/n}$ is simply *defined* as $\exp(\frac{m}{n}\log z)$. If the literature you are referring to also defines $z^{m/n}$ in this way, then there is no point of struggling with tautology. Otherwise, we need to know how $z^{m/n}$ is defined in order to initiate any meaningful discussion on it.

Comment: @SangchulLee  I may be misunderstanding the point. But as I understand the individual definitions of the left-hand side or the right-hand side is not important here; point here is equality of both sides; i.e. if you give me valid mathematical statement involving $z^{m/n}$, it will still be valid if I replace it by $e^{m/n\log z}$ and vice versa. In other words, if $z^{m/n}$ refers to a set of functions; then  $e^{m/n\log z}$  refers to the same set of functions.

Comment: @zimbra314, Why people are so caring about how $z^{m/n}$ is defined for complex $z$ is that your statement need not be true. Unlike in positive-real case, there is no canonical definition of it. It is not god-given. It does depend on how we choose the branch cut. And without specifying the branch cut we are using for each of $z^{m/n}$ and for $\log z$, not only we cannot prove the equality, but also we can choose different branch cuts for the quantities so that they are no longer equal.

Comment: @zimbra314 We actually encounter this example when dealing with the cubic root. We first learn the real cubic root and then later learn the principal cubic root, where $$(-8)^{1/3} = -2 \qquad \text{as real cubic root}$$ but $$(-8)^{1/3} = -1+i\sqrt{3} \qquad \text{as principal cubic root}$$ So, which choice is better? Sadly no such choice exists in general, as any branch cut is equally good.

Comment: In maths, equality is a very strong statement; if a=b and  a=c; then we must have b=c; In your example, we don't; so either of a=b or b=c must be wrong. What you are mathematically trying to say is one of the possible value of $(-8)^{1/3}$ is -2, and it is very different from saying $(-8)^{1/3}=-2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: $\log z$ has infinite values, i.e. $z=re^{i(\theta+2\pi k)}\implies \log z= log r+ i(\theta +2\pi k), k\in \mathbb{N}$;

Show that right-hand side has $n$ different values, and so is left-hand side.